# Issue with dropdown with image in bulma

Tags: css, bulma

I am trying to make a dropdown menu with the user image. however either the image is misplaced when I use    (1st case), or it is in the right place using only  but not rounded as I want (2nd case).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuCBd.jpg

I started using the image component as the bulma documentation says. I was going through some classes, I removed the  external to . without  I can't get the image to be round

1st case:

2nd case:

```
<div class="navbar-link">
<img src="image">
</div>
```

i wan this dropdown to be like the second case image but image with rounded shape

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this?

```
<div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
    <a class="navbar-link">
        <img
           src="https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/58e91a21eb97430e81906500.png" 
           style= "border-radius: 9001px;"
           alt="Placeholder image"
        >
    </a>
    <div class="navbar-dropdown">
        <a class="navbar-item">
         Jobs
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/bluebrown/pen/OJJggMM?editors=1000